# How can I create a distiniguish line in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Can any body teach how to create a distinguish line running through in the middle of box?

I want it to look like the line in this image:

[image]

EDIT NOTE: I lightened the image levels, and cropped to one side in order to avoid site resize. This was done so overall appearance can be better seen.

[image: ligthened]

Answer (score 4):

Essentially it's 4 simple objects, disregarding the background pattern.

- A white radial gradient with the bottom half removed
- A black line, 1 pixel tall, and fading to nothing on both ends.
- A 1 pixel white line which fades on both ends
- A black radial gradient with the top half removed.

[image: divider]